# readr reverse function to format_csv

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know that if I want to save `data.frame` to a string instead of a file I can user `readr` function `format_csv`.

```
data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c("a", 'c')) %>% 
   format_csv(col_names=T)
```

which produces

```
[1] "a,b\n1,a\n2,c\n"
```

Is there a reverse function relative to `format_csv`?

Or using `textConnection` together with `read.table` is the only way:

```
  con<-textConnection(csv, "r")
  tb<-read.table(file=con, sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
  close(con)
```

Comment: You can pass that string to `read_csv()` (note the underscore for the readr version). It takes a file path or a literal string with file contents.

Comment: you just need to make sure to wrap the name of the literal string or vector with `I()` as per the [documentation](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html): `tbl <- read_csv(I(name_of_vector))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these.  The `col_types` and `colClasses` arguments can be omitted if you don't require exactly the same types as the anonymous data frame shown in the question.

```
csv <- "a,b\n1,a\n2,c\n" # input

# 1
library(readr)
read_csv(csv, col_types = "nc")

# 2
read.csv(text = csv, colClasses = c("numeric", "character"))

# 3
library(data.table)
fread(csv, colClasses = c("numeric", "character"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and found the answer in the [`read_delim` documentation](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html):

> Literal data is most useful for examples and tests. To be recognised as literal data, the input must be either wrapped with I(), be a string containing at least one new line, or be a vector containing at least one string with a new line.

This was extremely useful because I needed to preprocess the literal strings of a file (change encoding, remove a bunch of control characters, etc.) which I did with regexes on a raw vector read with readLines:

```
raw_text <- readLines(mycsv)
clean_text <- raw_text |>
   iconv(from = "GB18030", to = "US-ASCII", sub = "") |>
   stringr::str_replace_all("\\035", ",") |>
   stringr::str_replace("\\v", "") |> 
   stringr::str_replace("(\\+)([^,].*)?(,)", "\\1\\3")

tbl <- read_csv(I(clean_text))
```